# Problems POSTing data to an asp.net webpage (problem in Desktop C# end)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thank you so much for taking the time to read my post! I am having a problem POSTing data from a C# Desktop application to a C# asp.net web page. I believe that the problem lies in the Desktop application (or at least one of the problems does!) I will also post the asp.net code I am using. If asp.net is not your speciality, don't worry, I was just wondering if there was anything glaringly obvious there as well.

I also had to create an asp.net website to post data to the Windows Forms application. This is working perfectly.

Here is the code I am using. What is not working is discussed below. I am very bad at all this asp.net stuff, so any help you can provide would be very much appreciated.

```
if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() && result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string test = "Test";
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.aspx");
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                // Give the response
                using (Stream datastream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }
             }
```

However, when I Debug the application, and put a breakpoint just after datastream.Write() I get some errors in the Variable Watch window. I do not get any exceptions except in there.

I cannot upload an image to this website it seems, so I shall upload it to a FreeWebs site - sorry, really embarrassing! [watch.jpg](http://rjnb.webs.com/watch.JPG)

As you can see, I am getting System.NotSupported on datastream.Length and datastream.Position

Could you please help me to fix this? Thanks!

Just in case an asp.net programmer also sees this, is there any problem with this receiving code?:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes).ToString();
    }
```

Thank you all, so, so much for your time!

Richard

EDIT: In relation to gandjustas's comment, I am providing more information.

Something in the chain is not working. I am not getting any formal exceptions to report.

If I use this code in the asp.net webpage:

```
 string test = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes).ToString();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(test);
        Response.End();
```

I get the following response back: System.Byte[]

This is not a variable, but a string containing the arbitrary words and symbols 'System.Byte[]'

Something is not working (obviously) I then see this System.NotSupportedException in my Watch window. This make me think that there are two errors: This System.NotSupportedException needs fixing in my C# Desktop Application, and my asp.net webpage should not be displaying System.Byte[] before I have even sent my POST from the application.

I kind of need help. Thanks!

Comment: What is an error? NotSuppeortedException in watch window or not sending request?

Comment: Is that enough extra detail, or have I left something out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of remarks about your code:

1. You are setting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type but you are sending some arbitrary byte array. When you set this content type the server will expect that the request is encoded using it.
2. The `NotSupportedException` you are getting in the Debug window are normal. You simply cannot use the `Length` property on a `NetworkStream`.

Let me try to simplify your code in case you really want to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

Client:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/test.aspx", values);
}
```

Server:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key1 = Request["key1"];
    string key2 = Request["key2"];
}
```

Comment: Hello! I thank you so much for your response! It is nearly working, but there is still one thing missing. The webpage end now works perfectly. If I put in: http://localhost:51274/test.aspx?key1=test&key2=test2 it will produce a perfect response. However, when I run my program, it still will not work properly. If I modify the the webpage to return the value of key1, key2, and then the word "Test" I get back the word "Test", so the webpage is obviously being called, but for some very strange reason, there is an ominous hole where value1 and value2 should appear. They are either not being

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: uploaded, or uploaded as completely blank. Any ideas? Thanks so much! P.S. Sorry for posting these so early, before I meant to, I am not used to enter being post rather than new line!

Comment: I got it to work! Busy now, but I will tell you how I did it tomorrow, so that others can benefit. Thank you all so, so much for all of your time! Richard

Comment: Basically, I just used this code. It was also quite a lot easier (possibly) because I only ever wanted to upload a string, rather than a file, but all the links still applied, and I needed to learn at some point. Thank you all so, so much for your time! Richard

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
           string test = "Test"; 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.aspx"); 

            request.Method = "POST"; 
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8"; 
            request.ContentLength = test.Length; 

           using (StreamWriter paramWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
           {
              paramWriter.Write(test, 0, test.Length);

           }

           WebResponse wres = request.GetResponse();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wres.GetResponseStream());
           string outdata = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes to try it!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using MSDN's [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) on WebRequest class, is that correct?

Try using the `NameValueCollection`, just as Darin said, and instead of using a byte array do as follows:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(test)) },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/test.aspx", values);
}
```

You can also try changing the content-type; please check the examples [here](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2009/11/10/upload-a-file-via-webrequest-using-csharp/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/9be81392-71b6-4424-aed4-0627f041ba2e).

Comment: I thank you so much for your reply! I did use that HowTo article, blindly copied application/x-www-form-urlencoded from it, and that seems to be half the problem! I am just going to read those two articles you linked to now. Thank you so much for such good links!